# Wrong answer to "FizzBuzz" style code

Tags: javascript, logic, jscript

The original question is:
What is the sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 from 1 to 1000?
I wrote this code to solve that.

```js
var array =[]; //Setting up the Array
for (i=0 ; i<1000 ; i++) {
    if(i %3 === 0) {
        array.push(i);
    } else if (i%5 === 0) {
        array.push(i);
    } else{ 
    };
}; //This is the main loop

var sum = array.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}); //array reduce function to summate the array.
```

Now This does return 467, but that does not seem to be the correct answer as you can see [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1)
Also, I am new here and would like to know how the code snippet works, because i am not getting a return value at all.
Also, how do I indent my code here? tab doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is correct. When I run it, it does not return 467. You ask how it works: "%" finds the remainder of a division. The last else is useless. It checks all numbers from 0 to 999 and looks for valid numbers, adding them to the array. The reduce just keeps a running tally behind the scenes and continues adding to it by passing it as a to your function and passing the next item in the array as b to the function. Indenting has to be done with [two or four] spaces on here as far as I know, and I'm not sure how to print in SO snippets. Thought it was `console.log`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t2qw158m/ check the console after you run with ctrl + shift + j

Comment: If I wanted to go do the first 1000 Numbers, I would need i= 1001, correct?
thanks. I'm going to test out console.log() on my original post.

Comment: Usually just put <= instead of changing to 1001. Whatever keeps the number even is usually preferred I think. It's all a matter of preference. 1001 works. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anything is wrong with your code - when I run it I get 233168 which seems right.

As for indenting your code, you have to use spaces. I usually indent in my text editor and then copy and paste in.

Finally for the code snippets I don't have much experience with them but I believe you need to log your answer to the console, not just return it.

```
var array =[]; //Setting up the Array
for (i=0 ; i<1000 ; i++) {
  if(i %3 === 0) {
    array.push(i);
  } else if (i%5 === 0) {
    array.push(i);
  }
} //This is the main loop
var sum = array.reduce(function(a,b) {
  sum = a+b;
  return a+b;
}); //array reduce function to summate the array.
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: now that you say it, when i reran my code it worked and didn't spit out 467, but instead 233168. I think Millie Smith edited it.
EDIT: Indeed she did, she changed the return a+b)}; into return a+b;

Comment: Note also that I removed the semicolons from the end of the for loop and if/else block. semicolons end lines not logic blocks or loops. Additionally I removed the empty else, which isn't necessary to have